# If $\varphi$ is progressively measurable, is $\int_0^t\varphi_s\:{\rm d}s$ adapted?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, filtrations

Let

- $T>0$
- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $[0,T]$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $(\varphi_t)_{t\in[0,\:T]}$ be a real-valued $\mathcal F$-progressively measurable stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $\operatorname P\left[\varphi\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)\right]=1$ and $$A_t:=\int1_{(0,\:t]}(s)\varphi(s)\:{\rm d}\lambda(s)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[0,T]$$

> How can we show that $A$ is $\mathcal F$-adapted?

It's clear that $A$ is $\operatorname P$-almost surely continuous and has $\operatorname P$-almost surely bounded variation.

Answer (score 2):

By progressive measurability, the restriction of $\varphi$ to $\Omega\times[0,t]$ is $\mathcal F_t\otimes\mathcal B([0,t])$-measurable. From this and Fubini it follows that for each positive integer $n$, 
$$
A^{(n)}_t:=\int_0^t 1_{\{|\varphi(s)|\le n\}}\varphi(s)\,ds
$$
is well-defined and $\mathcal F_t$-measurable. Finally, define $A_t:=\limsup_n A^{(n)}_t$. This random variable is also $\mathcal F_t$-measurable, and $A_t(\omega)=\int_0^t \varphi(\omega,s)\,ds$ for each $\omega$ for which $s\mapsto \varphi(\omega,s)\in L^1(\lambda)$, hence almost surely.

Comment: You shouldn't redefine the object $A_t$.

Comment: Your argument is based on the finiteness of $\operatorname P\otimes\left.\lambda\right|_{[0,\:t]}$. That's why $1_{\left\{\:\left|\left.\varphi\right|_{\Omega\times[0,\:t]}\right|\:\le\:n\:\right\}}\left.\varphi\right|_{\Omega\times[0,\:t]}\in\mathcal L^1\left(\operatorname P\otimes\left.\lambda\right|_{[0,\:t]}\right)$. It's intuitively plausible that $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_t^{(n)}=A_t$$ (with the $A_t$ in the question) $\operatorname P$-almost surely. But how do we see that rigorously?

Comment: Are you using that $1_{\left\{\:|\varphi|\:\le\:n\:\right\}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$? That shouldn't be true, unless $\varphi$ is bounded.

Comment: I've asked [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980542/how-can-we-prove-that-limsup-n-to-infty-int-0t1-left-phi-s-le-n-right) for that.

Comment: I'm using that $1_{\{|\varphi|\le n\}}\to 1$ a.s. together with the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I've actually meant $1_{\left\{\:|\varphi|\:\le\:n\:\right\}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$ in my comment above, but why does that hold, unless $\varphi$ is bounded? Moreover, Your proof doesn't work, unless $\mathcal F$ is complete (i.e. $\mathcal F_0$ contains the negligible events), right?

Comment: Because $s\mapsto \varphi(\omega,s)$ is integrable on $[0,T]$ for a.e. $\omega\in\Omega$, the modulus $|\varphi(\omega,s)|$ is finite for a.e. pair $(\omega,s)$. For a "good" pair $(\omega,s)$, $|\varphi(\omega,s)|\le n$ for all sufficiently large $n$, in which case $1_{\{|\varphi(\omega,s)|\le n\}}=1$. 
My proof proves what I asserted: there is an $\mathcal F_t$-measurable r.v. $A_t$ such that $A_t(\omega)=\int_0^t\varphi(\omega,s)\,ds$ for   every $\omega$ with  $s\mapsto \varphi(\omega,s)$ is integrable. You cannot hope for more without an additional completeness hypothesis.

Comment: (1) So, you agree to my last comment: We need completeness of $\mathcal F$; otherwise $A$ won't be $\mathcal F$-adapted, right? (2) In any case, I think we need to say something about the value of $A(\omega)$ with $\varphi(\omega)\not\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)$ and $\varphi(\omega)\not\ge 0$. I guess we need to redefine $A$ for those $\omega$ to be $0$ (for example), don't we? (3) Shouldn't we even got $1_{\left\{\:|\varphi|\:\le\:n\:\right\}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$ **surely**? Note that $\varphi$ is real-valued.

Comment: As I have defined it, for all $\omega\in\Omega$, $A_t$ is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable, though possible infinite. I'm not sure how *you* intended the integral $\int_0^t \varphi(\omega,s)\,ds$ to be defined when $s\mapsto\varphi(\omega,s)$ is not integrable. And yes, if $\varphi$ is real-valued, then $1_{\{|\varphi|\le n\}}\to 1$ everywhere.

Comment: I've made a mistake in formulating the question. If $\varphi$ is nonnegative, then we might consider the integral as being $[0,\infty]$-valued. But in general, the integral is not defined. So, I should have defined $A(\omega)=0$ for all $\omega\in N:=\left\{\varphi\not\in\mathcal L^1(\lambda)\right\}$. And my observation was: With the new definition, we need the completeness of $\mathcal F$, since then $1_{\Omega\setminus N}A_t^{(n)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}A_t$ and $1_{\Omega\setminus N}A_t^{(n)}$ is $\mathcal F_t$-measurable. Do you agree?

Comment: I agree.$\phantom{b}$